# SQLite Cascade Delete

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, windows-runtime

actually i'm developping windows metro app using SQLite DataBase. i use sqlite manager (mozilla) for administration. i tried delete cascade but it work only in sqlite manager not in C# code :

My function

---

```
public async Task<string> DeleteSurvey(int SurveyID)
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    var db = new SQLite.SQLiteAsyncConnection(App.DBPath);
    var survey = await GetSurvey(SurveyID);
    var res = await db.DeleteAsync(survey);

    if (res > 0)
        result = "Success";
    else
        result = "Echec";

    return result;
}
```

---

```
db.CreateTable<Survey>();

SQLiteCommand command1 = new SQLiteCommand(db);
command1.CommandText = "create table if not exists SurveyItemGroup";
command1.CommandText += "(ID integer primary key autoincrement not null, IDSurvey integer,";
command1.CommandText += "Number integer, Name varchar(50), FOREIGN KEY(IDSurvey) REFERENCES Survey(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)";
command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

In C# code it only delete survey table not both (Survey and SurveyItemGroup)

PS: I have the same problem with pragma (`pragma foreign_keys=ON;`) it works only if i do it sqlite manager.

Comment: I have tried to reproduce your problem using only the sqlite3 command line interface (sqlite3 command under Ubuntu 12.04), and I found the cascade delete works with `PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON` but doesn't work with `PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF`.

Comment: It might be a problem related to the particular sqlite version you're using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10719425/foreign-key-constraint-on-delete-cascade-not-working-in-sqlite-database-on-andro Mine is 3.7.9

Comment: #Marcello thank's for your answer ...I finally solved my problem. In fact, pragma_foreign=ON; must be done before after each database connection like this :

public async Task<string> DeleteSurvey(int SurveyID)
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    var db = new SQLite.SQLiteAsyncConnection(App.DBPath);
    var survey = await GetSurvey(SurveyID);
    var pragma = await db.executeAsync("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON");
    var res = await db.DeleteAsync(survey);

}

Comment: I guess you meant... pragma must be issued after connecting to the database and before issuing any query ;-)
Glad to have been of some help. You might want to write that comment down as a proper answer, and accept it yourself.

Answer (score 6):

(I'm adding this answer because the OP noted this as his solution, but only in a comment.)

Currently, for ON DELETE CASCADE to work, `pragma foreign_keys=on;` must be issued in *each* new connection. It's [not currently](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_foreign_keys) a persistent setting.