# Entity Framework hard cascade delete

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite

I have a SQLite DB mapped with Entity Framework.
There are 2 tables : Collections (1:n) Albums.

When I delete a collection, all related albums have to be deleted as well.
I use `CollectionRepo.Delete(collection);` to achieve that. It uses the following code :

```
public int Delete(Collection entity)
{
    Context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Deleted;
    return Context.SaveChanges();
}
```

The problem is: when I execute this code, `Context.SaveChanges();` give me an exception:

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

It seems that Entity Framework wants to `null` on the foreign keys instead of deleting the entries. But this is absolutely not what I want because an album makes no sense without a parent (in my use case at least).

I could obviously manualy delete the albums first and then delete the empty collection but it seems to me a bit tricky. First, it seems to me that EF should be smart enough to do it on it's own to simplify the code and second, what if I have dozens of relations to collections and albums, I would end up with quite a big, hard to maintain, code base.

---

**Collection Class**

```
public class Collection
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Album> Albums { get; set; } = new List<Album>();
}
```

**Album class**

```
public class Album
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("Collection")]
    public long CollectionId { get; set; }

    public virtual Collection Collection { get; set; }
}
```

**DbContext child class**

```
public class DataEntities : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<Collection> Collections { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Album> Albums { get; set; }

    public DataEntities() : base("name=Connection")
    {
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Album>()
            .HasRequired(a => a.Collection)
            .WithMany(c => c.Albums)
            .HasForeignKey(a => a.CollectionId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Collection>()
            .HasMany(c => c.Albums)
            .WithRequired(a => a.Collection)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of sqlite are you using? Sounds like it's an issue with sqlite not supporting cascade delete http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10719425/foreign-key-constraint-on-delete-cascade-not-working-in-sqlite-database-on-andro

Comment: 3.14.2 (System.Data.SQLite 1.0.103).
 
It doesn't seem to be related to SQLite IMHO, because the foreign key in my table allow null, plus the exception stack trace deepest call is `System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.PrepareToSaveChanges(SaveOptions options)` wich seems not yet related to SQLite.

Comment: You designated it as non-nullable in the mapping [Required][ForeignKey] that's why EF is confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Applying detached object graph modifications has always been unclear in EF. This is one of the cases where it fails without a good reason.

Assuming the `Collection` entity passed to the `Delete` method has `Albums` collection populated (at least this is how I was able to reproduce the exception). The line

```
Context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Deleted;
```

does two things: attaches `entity` and all `Album` objects from the `entity.Albums` to the context, marks `entity` as `Deleted`, and (note!) the `Album` objects as `Modified`. This leads to incorrect behavior when you call `SaveChanges`, and at the end generates the exception in question.

There are two ways (workarounds) to fix this incorrect behavior.

The first one is to replace the above line with

```
Context.Collections.Attach(entity);
Context.Collections.Remove(entity);
```

The effect is similar to the described above, with the importand difference that now the related `Album` objects arte marked as `Deleted`, which allows successfully executing the `SaveChanges`.

The drawback is that now the `SaveChanges` issues a `DELETE` command for each `Album` before the command for deleting the `Collection`, which is inefficient and doesn't make much sense since the cascade delete would handle that perfectly inside the database.

The second option is to keep the code as is, but clear the related collection before attaching the entity:

```
entity.Albums = null;
Context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Deleted;
```

This allows successfully executing `SaveChanges` and it generates a single `DELETE` command only for the entity.

The drawback is that you need to write additional code and not forget any child collection which supports cascade delete, and not doing that for collections that need cascade update (i.e. with optional relation which requires updating the FK field with `NULL`).

The choice is yours.

Comment: It works, thanks for that detailed explanation, even if it sounds to me quite unlogical/counter-intuitive (EF, not your explanation). What's the role of `WillCascadeOnDelete(true)` if it doesn't naturally handle the cascade deletion? Are you sure your first workaround a `delete`command for each `Album` instead of a batch `delete`, like `DELETE FROM Albums WHERE CollectionId = xxx`?

Comment: Yes, I tested it before answering. It executes N commands like `DELETE FROM Albums WHERE Id = @0`. Latest EF6.1.3, SqlServer db. What about the benefit of `WillCascadeOnDelete`, it's used to create the corresponding constraint in the database.

Comment: But I don't think the database matters since this seems to be performrf by the EF infrastructure, while the db provider just generates the corresponding SQL commands.

Comment: OK, thanks, just a last question, where can you trace the SQL commands issued and where did you debug what was actualy done to the object by the command `Context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Deleted;`?

Comment: (1) `Context.Log = Console.WriteLine;` or `Context.Log = s => Trace.WriteLine(s);` (2) Expand `Context.ChangeTracker.Entries()` in Watch

Comment: Actualy, it doesn't work. I'm using your first workaround and it worked for a single deletion but I have to delete some collections, so the delete method is called inside a foreach loop. It works for a few loops, the data is actualy removed from the db, but after some time the same error as before pops up (the context is filled up with the previous, already removed, collections and albums, with Album.Collection set to null).

Comment: You are not using the same context for retrieving the data, right? The assumption was that the data is disconnected (coming from outside). If you use the same context instance for other things, I have no idea what could happen.

Comment: Yes, I use the same context. I get all the entities with `Context.Albums.Include(a => a.Collection).ToList();` then I look for the albums that have to be deleted a linq query then I do a foreach loop on these entities. If the collection of that album has more than 1 album, I delete the album, else I delete the collection. The context is contained inside the AlbumRepo and CollectionRepo (wich handle the `GetAll()` and `Delete()` methods). The repositories class are created once and I do nothing more at that point.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134057/discussion-between-ivan-stoev-and-sebastien).

Answer (score 0):

Per your comments, you're mapping to a pre-existing database (EF did not generate it). CascadeOnDelete only affects the generation of the database. If the database doesn't have CascadeOnDelete configured on the table, then EF will be confused when it attempts to delete and Sqlite doesn't comply.

Also you have the mapping for the foreign key as non-nullable and required (redundant by the way) but in the database the foreign key is nullable. EF assumes that it's not valid because of what you told it.

If you fix your mapping (remove the required annotation from the CollectionID property and change its type to int? instead of just int you should fix your problem. Actually change the mapping in the DbContext class from HasRequired to HasOptional...from there it should work.

Either that or change the table definitions on your database itself.

Comment: I allowed null in the DB for debuging purpose only. Now I put it back tu `NOT NULL`  and the FK is `ON DELETE CASCADE`. I don't want to change my mapping from HasRequired to HasOptional because in my design an album shoud always be associated to a collection (the UI shows the collections and then the albums, so if an album is not associated to a collection, it will never be shown).

Comment: So after you put it back to not null and on delete cascade did that fix the problem?

Comment: No, that was the initial state, before I changed it to be sure it was not related to the DB. Ivan Stoev solved my problem in 2 acts : first by proposing the 2 workarounds in it's answer and second by pointing out that the DbContext should always be unique.